# Webpack: issue with breakpoints and mapping in typescript - breakpoints automatically moves at the end of file on debug

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

After I've updated webpack from 3.11.0 to 4.6.0, **breakpoints** in Angular Typescript **started moving automatically at the end of the file** during debug.

 If I stop debug, they returns where I've placed them.

> **EXAMPLE** (which will explain the situation better than my intro above)
>
> If I have - for example - a `.ts` file of 100 lines and I set a
>   breakpoint on typescript on Visual Studio at line 50, when I run my
>   app debug, the breakpoints moves automatically at the end of the file
>   (so at line 100). 
>  When I stop debug, it returns on line 50.

---

The issue started when I've updated Webpack to last version and seems like to be related to sourcemap.

**I share with you my webpack.config.js content below. After the code snippet, I will also tell you what I've changed from 3.11.0 to 4.6.0.**

Can anyone help me to solving this?

P.S.: I've kept the default line that enable in-line sourcemaps if you delete or comment it in the config file (see comment `Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps` in my code below) because using in-line sourcemaps on typescript literally kills my computer.

---

**MY CODE BELOW**

> **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/', // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
            globalObject: 'self'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'style-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                //font management
                {
                    test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                // specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    cache: true,
                    parallel: true,
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        compress: false,
                        ecma: 6,
                        mangle: true
                    },
                    sourceMap: true
                })
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

---

**WHAT CHANGED BETWEEN VERSIONS**

> **webpack.config.js**

**1. - moved uglify from plugins to optimization, but copy-pasting this configuration from the internet.** 
 (Maybe the issue is related to this?)

```
optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                // specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    cache: true,
                    parallel: true,
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        compress: false,
                        ecma: 6,
                        mangle: true
                    },
                    sourceMap: true
                })
            ]
        },
```

**2. - removed AOT webpack plugin from production environment configuration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by disabling browser link in Visual Studio 2017.

 Also set "sourcemap:true" on tsconfig.